# Cannot find a javascript function in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The form in this html has an onsubmit attribute which executes the codeAddress() function however in the Google Chrome Dev console it says that it cannot find it. The function is supposed to change the value of the "lat" and "lng" form inputs which have the display property set to "none" in a  seperate css file. Then the values are to be sent to a php file for processing.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="map.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="newelements.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="my_js.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      downloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {};

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function( event ){
  alert( "Latitude: "+event.latLng.lat()+" "+", longitude: "+event.latLng.lng() ); 
});

    function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    // );
             // what happens here?
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    };
    document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = point.lat().toFixed(5);
    document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = point.lng().toFixed(5);
  };

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <button type="button" id="krusts" onclick="div_show()" ></button>
    <div id="map" ></div>

        <div id="abc">

            <div id="popupContact">

                <form onsubmit="codeAddress()" action="registerEvent.php" id="form" method="post">

                    <h2 id="formvirsr">Ievadiet notikumu</h2>

                    <input id="nosaukums" name="nosaukums" placeholder="Nosaukums" type="text">
                    <input id="address" name="address" placeholder="Adrese" type="text">
                    <select name="veids" id="veids">
                      <option value="" disabled selected>Notikuma veids</option>
                      <option value="Viens">Viens</option>
                      <option value="Divi">Divi</option>
                      <option value="Tris">Tris</option>
                      <option value="Cetri">Cetri</option>
                    </select>
                    <input id="datums" name="datums" type="date">
                    <input id="laiks" name="laiks" type="time">
                    <input id="lat" name="lat" >
                    <input id="lng" name="lng" >                    
                    <textarea id="info" name="info" placeholder="Papildu info"></textarea>

                    <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>                 
                    <button type="button" id="close" onclick ="div_hide();">Close</button> <!-- aizversanas poga -->
                    <br>
                </form>
            </div>          
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script has some syntax errors. Please fix them before proceeding.

Comment: The JavaScript syntax is incorrect on your `codeAddress` function.

Comment: It cannot find it because it's not loaded because you most likely have errors in your JS. Check your console output for errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After fixing a few basic JavaScript syntaxic errors, you can call your codeAdress function.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="map.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="newelements.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="my_js.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      downloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {};

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function( event ){
  alert( "Latitude: "+event.latLng.lat()+" "+", longitude: "+event.latLng.lng() ); 
});

    function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    };
    document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = point.lat().toFixed(5);
    document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = point.lng().toFixed(5);
  });
}
  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <button type="button" id="krusts" onclick="div_show()" ></button>
    <div id="map" ></div>

        <div id="abc">

            <div id="popupContact">

                <form onsubmit="codeAddress()" action="registerEvent.php" id="form" method="post">

                    <h2 id="formvirsr">Ievadiet notikumu</h2>

                    <input id="nosaukums" name="nosaukums" placeholder="Nosaukums" type="text">
                    <input id="address" name="address" placeholder="Adrese" type="text">
                    <select name="veids" id="veids">
                      <option value="" disabled selected>Notikuma veids</option>
                      <option value="Viens">Viens</option>
                      <option value="Divi">Divi</option>
                      <option value="Tris">Tris</option>
                      <option value="Cetri">Cetri</option>
                    </select>
                    <input id="datums" name="datums" type="date">
                    <input id="laiks" name="laiks" type="time">
                    <input id="lat" name="lat" >
                    <input id="lng" name="lng" >                    
                    <textarea id="info" name="info" placeholder="Papildu info"></textarea>

                    <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>                 
                    <button type="button" id="close" onclick ="div_hide();">Close</button> <!-- aizversanas poga -->
                    <br>
                </form>
            </div>          
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly changed here? Readers don't want to scan through 127 lines of code to find the single syntax error. Could you add some context to what was actually fixed where in addition to the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

In fact you're closing the parenthesis of geocoder.geocode (line 80) in the middle of the "if" just below (line 82). It is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    // );
             // what happens here?
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    } // Close of else
    document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = point.lat().toFixed(5);
    document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = point.lng().toFixed(5);
  }); // Close of geocoder
} // Close of function codeAddress
```

Closing the functions appropriately.